# Copying/Migrating AzureML Service Experiments

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am using azure machine learning services. I have multiple experiments in my Azure Machine Learning Workspace. Now I want to copy or migrate my ml experiments on different subscription, so I can use my experiments on a different workspace subscription.

Is there any possible way to migrate or copy AzureML experiments to reuse ?

Thank you

Regards,

Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

In the previous version of AMLS, there were ways to do it in the UI but in the "current" version of the new AMLS (as of April 4th 2020), I only see option to do this using REST API. This article provides more details on how to export not just your workspace but also data, artifacts and other resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-export-delete-data

Comment: Thank you Vamsi Sistla  for your response. I will look into it